# Gostaria de verificar no cadastro de cliente se o código digitado já existe. Como faço?

Tags: c#, .net, array, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AtFinal
{
    class Program
    {

        struct Cliente
        {
            public int cod_cli;
            public string nome, endereco, telefone;
        }

        struct Recebimento
        {
            public decimal valorDoc;
            public DateTime dataEmissao, dataVencimento;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cliente[] clientes = new Cliente[5];
            Recebimento[] recebimentos = new Recebimento[15];

            int qtdCliente = 0;
            int qtdRecebimento = 0;
            int opcao = -1;

            do
            {
                Console.Title = " * SISTEMA DE RECEBIMENTOS * ";
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;// Muda a cor da tela.
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;// Muda a cor da letra.
                Console.Clear(); //limpa a tela

                //Imprime na tela as opções do Menu:
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("     MENU DE OPÇÕES      ");
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine(" Informe a opção deseja: \n");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Cadastrar Cliente");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Alterar Cliente");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Cadastrar Recebimento");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Sair");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(25, 3); //Move o cursor para o fim da 4a linha

                //lê a opção escolhida pelo usuário
                opcao = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                //limpa a tela
                Console.Clear();


                //direciona o programa para a opção escolhida pelo usuário:
                switch (opcao)
                {
                    case 1:
                    //Testa se já chegou ao limite de clientes cadastrados
                    //onde o limite é o tamanho (Length) do vetor:
                    if (qtdCliente < clientes.Length)
                    {
                        //Preenche os dados do cliente
                        Console.WriteLine("Digite os dados do cliente \n");
                        Console.Write("Código: ");
                        clientes[qtdCliente].cod_cli = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Nome: ");
                        clientes[qtdCliente].nome = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Endereço: ");
                        clientes[qtdCliente].endereco = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Telefone: ");
                        clientes[qtdCliente].telefone = Console.ReadLine();

                        //incrementa o número de clientes
                        qtdCliente++;

                        Console.WriteLine("\nCliente Cadastrado com sucesso!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Número máximo alcançado: " + qtdCliente);
                    }

                    Console.Write("\nPressione qualquer tecla para voltar ao menu.");

                    //Aguarda o usuário pressionar qualquer tecla para continuar:
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine(" vazio ");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //Testa se já chegou ao limite de Recebimentos cadastrados
                        //onde o limite é o tamanho (Length) do vetor:
                        if (qtdRecebimento < recebimentos.Length)
                        {
                            //Preenche os dados dos Recebimentos
                            Console.WriteLine("Digite os dados dos Recebimentos \n");
                            Console.WriteLine("Número do documento: " + (qtdRecebimento + 1));
                            Console.Write("Valor R$: ");
                            recebimentos[qtdRecebimento].valorDoc = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.Write("Data de emissão: ");
                            recebimentos[qtdRecebimento].dataEmissao = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.Write("Data de vencimento: ");
                            recebimentos[qtdRecebimento].dataVencimento = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());

                            qtdRecebimento++;

                            Console.WriteLine("\nRecebimento cadastrado com sucesso!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Número máximo já alcançado: " + qtdRecebimento);
                        }

                        Console.Write("\nPressione qualquer tecla para voltar ao menu.");

                        //Aguarda o usuário pressionar qualquer tecla para continuar:
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.Title = " * SAIR * ";
                        Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("Saindo do Sistema");
                        Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;

                    default: //executado quando o usuário escolhe uma opção que não existe
                        Console.Title = " * INVALIDO * ";
                        Console.WriteLine("---------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("Opção inválida!");
                        Console.WriteLine("---------------");
                        Console.Write("\nPressione qualquer tecla para voltar ao menu.");
                        //Aguarda o usuário pressionar qualquer tecla para continuar:
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                }
            } while (opcao != 4);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, realmente não sei a sua necessidade. Mas pedir ao usuário indicar um código numérico que deve ser único jamais será uma boa idéia. Desculpa mas qual a real necessidade disto? Esta informação será persistida em um banco de dados ou ficará armazenada só até a aplicação ser finalizada?

Comment: não ficará armazenada, será apenas usada até a aplicação ser finalizada. Não estamos usando banco de dados, é uma aplicação do tipo Console. Modifiquei o campo código para não ser inserido pelo usuário e sim gerado automaticamente. Mas preciso pegar esse campo "código" do cliente para utilizá-lo em Recebimento... pois é através dele que poderei verificar quantos recebimentos há por cliente... compreende? Pois cada cliente só poderá ter 3 recebimentos associado...

Comment: Entendi, obrigado por esclarecer. Assim que tiver um tempo disponível vou te auxiliar, se ninguém o tiver feito ainda.

Comment: Agradeço muito, esse é um trabalho de final de período. Consiste em, utilizando os registros a seguir, faça:
CLIENTE
- cod_cli
- nome
- end
- tel
RECEBIMENTO
- numDoc
- data_emissao
- data_venc
- cod_cli
a) Incluir Recebimento (verificar se o cliente já se encontra cadastrado);
b) alterar cadastro de Clientes (Usuário deve informar o cod_cli q será alterado);
c) Mostrar todos Recebimentos com data de vencimento dentro de um período qualquer. Mostrar tb nome do cliente e o total de dias em atraso, ñ havendo mostrar zero;
d) Só poderá cadastrar no máximo 3 recebimentos por cliente.

Comment: Até o momento @BrunoBermann, ninguém me auxiliou... :-(

Comment: Outra questão @BrunoBermann  é que para essa atividade só podemos usar: Struct, Sub-rotina, Ponteiros, Vetor, e os velhos conhecidos Laços de Repetição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais simples é usando LINQ, o que parece já estar preparado para usar. Então pode fazer uma consulta de forma simples:

```
var codCli = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //isso pode dar erro fácil
if (clientes.Contains(codCli)) {
    //aqui pede o resto dos dados
    clientes[qtdCliente].cod_cli = codCli;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/FindId.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_).

Só quero ressaltar que entendo que isso seja um exercício, mas em uma aplicação real o código será considerado repleto de erros. Ele só funciona em circunstâncias bem específicas. Fora isso falta bastante organização nele.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown, irei tentar...